# Are all questions relating to Chef off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, close-reasons

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050976/chef-how-to-globally-add-a-location-to-path) about using Chef to manipulate environment variables for the users I create during a Chef run. Initially, my question did refer specifically to Ubuntu, however I modified it to be less specific after some comments were posted. Now though, it has been put on hold as 5 people have voted it off-topic (none put a comment to explain it, I'm sure they're very busy
people...).

So I have three questions (naughty I guess, but they're related):

1. What's wrong with my question as it stands?
2. Is it off-topic for Stack Overflow to post *any* questions about Chef? I can't see why it would be - after all, Chef is about treating infrastructure as code, but am I missing something?
3. Should the Chef tag therefore be burninated (if that's the word, first time meta-user!)

Comment: I would add how you used the template option and appending a line to the file to make clear you tried those. Without those it might get too broad close votes. I won't call those question off-topic ...

Comment: Thanks @rene, the reason I didn't put examples of how I used those was because I didn't - they were inappropriate for my use case.  I take your point though, although the votes to close were for "off-topic", not "too broad".

Comment: Well, you're _using_ something, not _programming_ something, making it off-topic. There really isn't much to it.

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka - apologies if I'm being thich here, but can you explain that for me.  How is using Chef not programming? "Infrastructure as code" is how I believe it's described.

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka Worth adding [this link](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/database/blob/master/libraries/provider_database_mysql.rb) as exemple on how a cookbook can be programming related.

Comment: @IBam Your question in specific should be in http://superuser.com/ or http://askubuntu.com/.

Comment: @Tensibai Did you read his question? Not _all_ Chef related questions should be in Super User. But this one in specific, yes.

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka I disagree, the question is how to use Chef recipes to modify environment variables (managing files, etc), so it is about how to write Ruby code in chef DSL in particular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, you're question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284517/how-can-you-use-a-chef-recipe-to-set-an-environment-variable/14917841#14917841) and Chef being what it is, you're always on a razor blade when asking about it on Stack Overflow.
Edit: but now there's [devops.se](https://devops.stackexchange.com) where those questions will be welcomed

The best I can say about it is show some code of your ideas like

```
execute "Add my env var" do
  cmd "echo export VAR=#{node['my_attr']['value']} >> /etc/profile"
  not_if 'grep 'export VAR=#{node['my_attr']['value']}' /etc/profile
end
```

and say you find this not ideal as if value comes to change the old line will stay in the file and you start having to shave a yak about managing this in your recipe.

This is usually enough to get back in-topic as it include code and an explanation of why it does not fit.

---

My comment about [chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef) was targeted to someone in particular, which sounded to have no clue of what Chef DSL is and sounded to me seeing it from a "another language" point of view.

There's a lot of question in [chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chef) which are off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I think there's still questions on the tag really on topic so it should stay. How could it be cleaned, I've no idea.

Comment: thanks, a helpful answer to the question! I was going to suggest you change your comment on my original question to make it an answer, as I think you're right about it being a duplicate - of an apparently on-topic question ;-) but I guess while it's on hold you can't. Next time I have a Chef question maybe I'll open a new, disposable SO account to take the heat!

Comment: @Peter thanks for reminding me of this answer so I can update it :)

Answer (score -2):

The only thing that would make a question off topic for Stack Overflow is if it's not:

> a practical, answerable problem that is ***unique* to software development**

Now, if your question isn't *unique* to software development, it isn't within the scope of Stack Overflow. The usage of Chef in this case isn't something that only a software developer will find wanting to do, but almost every system administrator would find themselves in the same situation.

So, I would say that your question would be more fitting on our sisters sites that deal with administering systems, rather than just programers doing programing. (Oh, btw, I disagree with most reasonings exposed on the comments there)

Comment: Personally I think Chef fits under software development better than it fits under systems admin, as you are writing code and tests.  By your reasoning though, I think you'd agree that all Chef questions are off-topic - or can you think of an example that would be on-topic?

Comment: @IBam I'm not that knowledgeable about Chef, but as long as it isn't pure "configuration management" or at very least a "configuration management" task intimately related to programing (using ruby (a programming language) to create a cookbook) it would be fine on SO.

Comment: I'd argue that Chef is software development more than systems admin.  It is using software to do things that a sysadmin might wish to do, but that doesn't make it systems admin.  Have a search for questions tagged Chef, and see what percentage would, under your definition, belong on SO?

Comment: @IBam in my point of view, very few are about recipe code sadly. I agree question like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933157/replacing-a-template-in-a-wrapper-cookbook) are on topic for SO, most others are not but there's more people having a look over it on SO than on sister sites.

Comment: DSLs intended primarily for use by sysadmins are always going to be difficult to resolve. Shell scripting generally is considered programming, exim filter files probably aren't even though they have logical conditionals, every case has aspects that are like programming and others you'd consider to be "just text-based configuration". And for that matter, is writing 10 lines of Python "unique to software development", and that 10-line program is "software"? Maybe, but it only *always* is, if all programming is "software development".