# Are edits acceptable that remove "bias" from answers?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, etiquette

I was reviewing [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8525501) by another user. The editor is attempting to make the answer less biased by completely removing part of the answer.

Original answer:

> Of course they can see what you add/change on your control panel. They are administrator, they can do anything they want. But, please dont worry, reputable hosting provider will keep save your data and they wont steal anything.

Edited answer:

> Of course they can see what you add/change on your control panel. They are administrator, they can do anything they want.

Edit summary:

> Making this answer a little unbiased :) Thanks!!

I don't disagree with the spirit of the edit; the sentence that was removed didn't add anything to the answer and it was unsubstantiated. However, my inclination was to reject the edit on the basis that if a user makes a contentious claim, you should refute via a comment, rather than just edit it away.

Should this sort of edit be rejected?

Comment: You obviously removed the message the answers OP wanted to give. Biased or not, that's a radical change.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just to be clear, I did not edit anything. I was reviewing the edit. I haven't taken any action. I just want to err on the side of caution when rejecting edits.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: mtinsley cannot suggest edits, and certainly didn't suggest that one.

Comment: Ah, THX for clarifying. The edit should be rejected, yes.

Comment: The question author made a similar edit to the other answer as well.  They should probably both be rejected.

Comment: I think that more than anything is: why are cpanel questions on topic anyways?

Comment: That *more* than anything? So you think it's not an issue on, say, questions that aren't about cPanel?

Comment: @Braiam Why not? Why do many on SO keep pretending than how to deploy their applications or having some reasonable understanding of the environment they're running on isn't the developer's concern? (Not that I'm a big fan of cPanel or similar tools.)

Comment: The question is completely off topic and needs to be nuked.

Comment: The answer is very poor quality to begin with.  But a question or answer should never be edited in a way that changes the sense intended by the original author.

Comment: @Bruno my very biased experience have demonstrated, that to manage some cPanel you don't need a developer, nor is specific to programming.

Comment: @HotLicks relevant http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288802/is-it-ok-to-edit-the-question-to-change-the-authors-intention/288836?s=3|0.0000#288836

Comment: @Braiam I can't stand cPanel but I think it's definitely obtuse and quirky enough to be on topic here.  Sometimes it works like it's supposed to, and sometimes it takes a lot of very technical digging to get it to do even simple things correctly.

Comment: @aroth it's a tool primarily indended for server administrators, not developers. Hence off-topic. That most users of cPanel are developers who also administer their own server doesn't change that.

Comment: @Braiam I never said you needed to be a developer to manage cPanel, but it's typical for a number of developers to have to use that sort of tools, like many other little bits of developer-oriented sysadmins, that are not real professional sysadmin (so off-topic on ServerFault).

Comment: @CodeCaster Clearly, it's not for server administrators, at least not "professional" ones, according to SF: http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8086/47187

Comment: @Bruno I'm not a ServerFault frequent visitor, so apparently it's off-topic there as _"any cPanel question is crap, and cPanel messes so much with your system we don't want to figure out the commandline solution to your problem"_ (paraphrased). I think it's off-topic on SO too, so where should they go?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think [developer-oriented sysadmin questions (not necessarily cPanel)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295094/372643) can be on-topic here (maybe cPanel would work better on Webmasters.SE, although AFAIK, it's not purely for web config... if only SF wasn't so strict..). There's talk of a DevOps SE site, but I'm not sure too much fragmentation is good. At the end of the day, many developers have to know a little bit about sysadmin (or do some themselves) as part of the development of their applications. Questions that bridge the gap between the two disciplines can be fine on SO.

Comment: Bruno CodeCaster @aroth and anyone interested http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259218/213575

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that the question and answer pair was not a good fit for Stack Overflow, the issue raised was for this specific type of edit.

Removing the intention of the poster from their post is not a productive edit, and is also discouraged in the side bar of the edit interface (not that many people seem to pay attention to that side bar). It is there nonetheless.

[image]

Removing an entire sentence from a post (aside from common greetings or [thanks in advantage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/1026459)) definitely is changing some meaning of the post as it has removed content. It is also disrespectful to directly remove content from a post.

Yes, removing that type of content through a suggested edit should be rejected.

[Further reading on respecting the original author by Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/1026459)

Comment: I'd say that every language change changes meaning to some degree, and also that removing whole sentences sometimes changes meaning very little.