Post about programmatically upgrading an OS using Salt incorrectly closed

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: using salt to upgrade Linux Mint OS
This post was closed without any specific explanation. According to the boilerplate,

This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. You can edit the question so it's on-topic or see if it can be answered on another Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read the on-topic page for a site before posting there.

The tags for the question were both salt and salt-stack (the former tag somehow did not appear). It was a question about how to use salt to update the OS of clients, something that is not obviously possible, since the salt client processes depend on the underlying OS to work. The question is obviously one about a programming problem, as can be seen from the one answer supplied, which is a programming solution. The closing administrator did not suggest why this question did not qualify and did not suggest where I might repost the question. I would like the question reopened, since I am setting up a development environment to test the solution and would like the opportunity to interact with the person who supplied the answer on any problems that might arise.
There is a discussion of whether questions about SALT (and other distributed configuration programming languages) should be considered on-topic. The response with the highest score (19) advocates that these questions should be considered on topic. The first sentence of this response is:

If it's about programming Ansible / Puppet / Chef / Salt to do a specific task, it's on topic.

The argument is hard to summarize, but suggests that if these are off topic then questions about SQL, prolog and logbook should also be off topic.
So, I would argue that the languages that support these applications are legitimate programming languages and therefore should be considered on topic.
However, I am open to moving this question to another site, but there seems not to be a consensus where to post.

You were left a comment which very explicitly told you that the question isn't programming related and where it was on-topic. I don't see how the answer is at all about programming. It's just system administration.

'The tags for the question were both "salt" and "salt-stack" (the former tag somehow did not appear).' - The tag "salt" has been removed by the editor, since it has nothing common with your question: description of the tag [tag:salt] clearly says that it is for cryptographics.

"I would like the question reopened, since I am setting up a development environment to test the solution and would like the opportunity to interact with the person who supplied the answer on any problems that might arise." You still have that opportunity. You can comment on their answer even if the question is closed.

"The closing administrator did not suggest why this question did not qualify and did not suggest where I might repost the question." The question was closed by three regular users, not a moderator, and you did receive a comment suggesting that you try asking on Unix & Linux instead.

"The question is obviously one about a programming problem, as can be seen from the one answer supplied, which is a programming solution." I'm not convinced that using a command line interface can inherently be considered "programming".

If you truly desire a favorable action, please consider responding to the comments made to your meta post. Best to comment in as objective a fashion as possible, stating why you disagree with comments made (if you do), and consider searching the meta site for similar posts with answers that support your assertations.

Relatedly, I've written up a proposal to make the tags discussed here clearer (as well as a couple other related tags)

The answer you got does not seem to include programming in salt, merely configuring and running it. Note that the meta question you now refer to only seems to consider the first to be on topic, but does not seem to say anything about the latter.

I removed the salt tag because it was inappropriate. The tag description for the salt tag1 reads

Cryptography function that takes random bits and a string (typically a
password) and uses a one-way hash to provide a new string that can be
used for authentication without providing access to the original
string. If a salt function uses enough random bits, the resulting
string is generally considered cryptographically secure.

It's not a great description, but it's clearly referring to the cryptography usage of the term. This is an easy mistake to make since you are using a tool by the same name, that's why it's important to read the tag descriptions before using them.
As for my close vote (1 of 3), I have my own sense of where the boundary lines are for on-topic/off-topic, but I am of course fallible. However, I don't find your argument for re-opening your question convincing. The answer doesn't look like a programming solution to me. Both the question and the answer strike me as configuration issues for a configuration management tool.

1 It has since been renamed to salt-cryptography, with a new description.

Pardon me if I am mistaken, but I think you are unfamiliar with Salt. Yes, it is a configuration application, but the Salt language supports not only linear logic, but also looping (see https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.loop.html). The Salt language is a frontend for Python code and therefore supports programming solutions. However, if you are still unconvinced, would inform me if Unix & Linux admit questions about Salt? It would be pretty frustrating for me to submit the question there only to have it closed.

@dnessett: Yes, it would be frustrating to post it in another Stack site only to have it closed there. You could wait for more feedback on this question to see if there is a consensus. I will certainly be monitoring this question.

I just found this discussion of whether Salt questions are on-topic : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294923/are-ansible-puppet-chef-salt-questions-on-topic/ The answer with the highest score (19) seems to suggest they are, but there is the problem of where to post. I am open to moving my question to the correct place, but there seems not to be a way to find out where to put it.

@dnessett: I recommend you edit your question above to include that link and a summary of what you found there.

Dammit. Where am I supposed to ask questions about the Angelina Jolie movie now?

I have reposted the question (and answer) on Server Fault (link)
